# Finding the radians of a circle and a sphere

Tags: function, matlab, volume, area

So I'm trying to find the radians of a circle and a sphere by their formulas of area and volume. What is wrong with my code?

```
function my_eval_paramereters=calculations(rad1,rad2)
E_C = input('enter value for E_C:...');
rad1 = pi*(rad1*rad1);
rad2 = input('enter value for V_S:... ');
rad2(rad2) = (4/3)*pi*(rad2^3);
[rad1, rad2] = my_eval_parameters(E_C,rad2);
end
```

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear.  What does your code currently do?  What did you expect it to do?  Can you provide an example?  In addition to any programming errors, it looks like you trying to compute the area of a circle and sphere, you may want to update the title to reflect this.

Comment: There is a lot wrong with this codes snippet but GrapefruitIsAwesome is correct to suggest that the question needs more clarity in order for people to help you. Right off the bat, though a couple things jump out at me. You seem to reassign values to your input arguments in lines 3 and 4 and the output variable is likewise confusing---and is stored back in the input arguments?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.